# Using $_GET on other pages

Tags: php

I have a search file - dir/search.php

In search.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="timeout.js"></script>
```

In timeout.js:

```
<script src="functions.php"></script>
```

In functions.php in one line I have:

```
document.write('<?php if (!isset($_GET["r"])) { echo "error"; } elseif ($_GET["r"] ==     "top") { ?><title>Top Results</title><?php } ?>');
```

I was wondering why when I looked at search.php?r=top, it would display "error"?

Comment: What you mean with 'In search.php:' or 'In timeout.js:'.. etc?

Comment: can you post more of your code.

Comment: I'm afraid you are totally mixing up Javascript and PHP here.

Comment: @OptimusCrime calm down... I was editing my post since the code wouldn't show up.

Comment: @bažmegakapa Yeah I know it's a big mess :) Thanks for editing my post, I realize now that there must be a line of space between text and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can do crazy stuff like [src'ing PHP files in script tags](http://www.impressivewebs.com/php-file-html-script-tag/), the file you source has to be a PHP file which outputs javascript.

In this case, functions.php is actually javascript that outputs PHP.  This will never run as it's expecting PHP.

Comment: I see. For this specific case, I cannot use include so I ended up calling the php file through a script tag.

Comment: Right, but functions.php has javascript, not php . . . re-write the logic in PHP, and have it output javascript . . .

Comment: Oh you're right. That's the same tutorial I was reading to do this. Oddly enough, when I use document.write() to start the PHP file, the PHP within runs fine. The only thing that wouldn't work was the $_GET. I will try to change the file to the format you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try including functions.php with functions.php?r=top.  I'd bet your output changes.